# Comparing cat output as variable

Tags: linux, bash, ping

I am trying to make a script were it compares the output of the /results file when it equals 1.

```
#!/bin/sh

RESULTS=/results
$
while true
do
ping -c 5 1.1.1.1 > /dev/null && echo "1" > /results  || echo "0" > /results
if

         [ $RESULTS = "1" ];
then
        echo "working"
        sleep 5
else

        echo "not working"
        sleep 5
fi

done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Security issue

You should not be writing anything in `/results`.  You should avoid running anything as user `root` if you can, and you should not be able to scribble in the root directory if you are not user `root`.

#### Method issue

You're trying to test whether `ping` works the (really) hard way.  Use:

```
while true
do
    if ping -c 5 1.1.1.1 > /dev/null
    then echo "working"
    else echo "not working"
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

You might want to time-stamp your messages too; it is easier than counting.  Therefore:

```
while true
do
    if ping -c 5 1.1.1.1 > /dev/null
    then date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S - working"
    else date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S - not working"
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

Note that this technique avoids temporary files, so there is nothing to clean up.  This is better scripting technique.  Avoid temporary file when you can.  When you can't avoid temporary files, make sure they are cleaned up.

#### Making your technique work

Don't forget to use `$RESULTS` consistently.  I've also relocated the file to a 'better' location, and made reasonably sure that it will be cleaned up.  If `root`'s home directory is `/` (the traditional value) rather than `/home/root` or something similar, then consider using a different 'better' location such as `/tmp/root/results.$$` (creating the `/tmp/root` directory first: `mkdir -p /tmp/root`).

You need to compare the contents of `$RESULTS` with the string, rather than compare the name of `$RESULTS` with `0` or `1` (which will always be unequal).

This script uses a Bash-specific notation (the `$(<file)` notation reads the file):

```
RESULTS=$HOME/results.$$
trap "rm -f $RESULTS; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

while true
do
    ping -c 5 1.1.1.1 > /dev/null && echo "1" > $RESULTS  || echo "0" > $RESULTS
    if [ $(<$RESULTS) = "1" ];
    then echo "working"
    else echo "not working"
    fi
    sleep 5
done

rm -f $RESULTS
trap 0
```

Or (not restricted to Bash):

```
RESULTS=$HOME/results.$$
trap "rm -f $RESULTS; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

while true
do
    ping -c 5 1.1.1.1 > /dev/null && echo "1" > $RESULTS  || echo "0" > $RESULTS
    if [ $(cat $RESULTS) = "1" ];
    then echo "working"
    else echo "not working"
    fi
    sleep 5
done

rm -f $RESULTS
trap 0
```

(I note that the loop won't exit unless interrupted, so the post-loop cleanup is superfluous here, but it is what you should use in general to clean up temporary files.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to read the **content** of the file whose name is contained in the variable `RESULTS`, the expression

```
[ $RESULTS = "1" ]
```

must be changed to

```
[ $(cat $RESULTS) = "1" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `RESULTS` always holds `/results` and thus `[ $RESULTS = "1" ]` fails because `RESULTS` is never `"1"`. You need to compare the **content** of the file to which the path is stored in `RESULTS` with `"1"`; i.e. use `$(cat $RESULTS) = "1"`.

Answer (score 0):

Other answerers have suggested good scripting alternatives, but I think the easiest way to accomplish what you're looking to do is use [watch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch), which comes installed on most (all?) Linux distros. You could do something like this:

```
watch 'ping -c 5 2>&1 >/dev/null && echo "success" || echo "failure"'
```

Jonathan Leffler's solution is also very good, but in case you need to reuse the exit code of a command, the `$?` variable always contains the exit code of the previous command. You could store it to another variable and save it for later.